# Java 2d array counts zeros in column

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I start learning programming about 4 days ago by myself and iam a lil bit stuck with 2d arrays. I try to challenging myself with tasks, like get from 2d array column with most zeros or atleast  just count zeros, so far  i get this far

```
public class b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = new int [5][5];
        int i,j;
        int s = 0;

        for(i= 0;i<a.length; i++)
            for(j = 0; j<a[i].length; j++){
                a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            }
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");   
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(j=0;j<a[0].length;j++) {
            for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
                if(a[i][j] >-1 || a[i][j]<1) {
                    s++;
                    System.out.println(s +"\t");            
                    s = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }       
}
```

Can somebody explain me why result is always 1 and why it counts columns and rows in one row?

Comment: because you are reassingning `s = 0;`

Comment: If you are just learning programming, please get into the habit of correctly indenting your code - basically, increase your indent when you open a block with {, decrease it immediately before you close a block with }. It makes it a lot easier for others (and you) to read your code.

Comment: @singhakash without that it counts 1,2,3,4 and so on

Comment: @ArtG move the printing line outside the loops

Comment: @rohit-jain you have changed the semantics of the code with your edit - the second nested for loop now prints a newline for every j, whereas previously it only printed it for every i.

Comment: Man, I only discovered SO about a year ago, after fifteen years of programming. If only I discovered it on the fourth *day*.

Comment: @aliteralmind well, youtube is full with tutorials, its not hard to learn basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the condition enters into  `if(a[i][j] >-1 || a[i][j]<1)` then you increase s by 1 then print it which gives `1` then you reassign it to `s=0` so it gives same `1` each time.So remove the `s=0` and place the printing line after end of loop

```
public class b {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[][] = new int [5][5];
    int i,j;
    int s = 0;

    for(i= 0;i<a.length; i++)
        for(j = 0; j<a[i].length; j++){
            a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        }
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)

        System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
        System.out.println();   
    }

   for(j=0;j<a[0].length;j++){
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if(a[i][j] >-1 && a[i][j]<1){
        s++;

       }
    System.out.println("Zero in column no. "+j+" is "+s +"\t");
    s=0;
    }

  }   
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/7pwMwz)

Comment: How does it find the column with max count of zero?

Comment: @RohitJain OP doesnt ask to find the max it ask why it only prints 1?

Comment: @singhakash thank you for your response, but if rows are not equal to columns, then i got an error somthing like "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" I need to add exception or what?

Comment: @ArtG that was my mistake corrected it now and added a demo also,check my edits

Comment: @singhakash thank you very much, now I began to think that Java is more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Result will be 1 because you're re-assigning `0` to `s` everytime. But the issue is not only that.

Firstly your condition is using wrong indices. Instead of `a[i][j]` you should use `a[j][i]` as you're traversing column-wise. Secondly:

```
if(a[j][i] >-1 || a[j][i]<1){
```

can be simply written as:

```
if(a[j][i] == 0) {
```

So the structure is the outer `for` loop will iterate over each column number. And for each column number, inner `for` loop will find count of `0`. You've to maintain a `max` variable outside both the loops, to track the current max. Also, you've to use another variable inside the outer `for` loop to store the count for current column.

Everytime the inner `for` loop ends, check if current column count is greater than `max`. If yes, reset `max`.

```
int max = 0;
for(j=0;j<a[0].length;j++){
    int currentColumnCount = 0;
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[j][i] == 0) {
            currentColumnCount++;
        }
    }
    if (currentColumnCount > max) {
        max = currentColumnCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: about that first iif(a[j][i] >-1 || a[j][i]<1) but it isn't wrong? as integer holds only whole number without numbers after comma? And in your example, it counts zeros in whole array, but how can i count zeros by each row?